# Scroll animation component did not work with Next.js, but it worked with create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I recently migrated a small project from Create React App (CRA) to Next.js.

All is fine besides that my code for scroll animations suddenly does not work in Next.js and I am not sure why. And it does not throw errors; the animation just does not happen at all.
But it worked perfectly fine inside my Create React App project.

I am not sure where the issue is. How can I fix it?

This is the component.

```
 'use client';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export interface IProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  variant: 'slideFromRight' | 'slideFromLeft';
}

function useIsVisible(ref: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>) {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
      //remove if for more than one animation
      if (entry.isIntersecting) setVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
    });
    if (ref.current !== null && observer.takeRecords().length === 0)
      observer.observe(ref.current);
    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  });

  return visible;
}

export default function ScrollAnimation(props: IProps) {
  // State handling
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const visible = useIsVisible(ref);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <div className={visible ? 'animate-' + props.variant : 'notVisible'}>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then I import it and wrap it this way:

```
<ScrollAnimation variant="slideFromRight">
    <h1 className="text-white font-bold text-2xl ">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <hr className="border border-white my-4" />
        <p className="text-white font-montserrat text-left font-bold">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
      </ScrollAnimation>
```

The slideFromLeft and Right is declared in my [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/) configuration:

```
keyframes: {
        slideFromLeft: {
          '0%': {
            transform: 'translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)',
            visibility: 'hidden',
          },
          '100%': {
            transform: 'translateZ(0)',
          },
        },
        slideFromRight: {
          '0%': {
            transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)',
            visibility: 'hidden',
          },
          '100%': {
            transform: 'translateZ(0)',
          },
        },
      },
       animation: {
        slideFromLeft: '3s both slideFromLeft ',
        slideFromRight: '3s both slideFromRight ',
      },
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) entry with a minimal reproducible code example, but the animation never gets triggered. However, the same code works in a Create React App (CRA) setup without issues.

[CodeSandbox entry](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/black-firefly-4wtymh?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A22%2C1-22%2C15)

Here are some additional information regarding the answer of Siavash1991.

1. There aren't any errors in the browser console
2. Intersection Observer is supported in all browsers, and I do not use an old environment
3. *refCurrent* is not null
4. CSS animations are correctly defined in my [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/) configuration. As I said, the same setup works in CRA.
5. Parent component is rendered properly. Same here, the setup is identical on CRA
6. All dependencies are up-to-date. I just use React and Next.js and no other dependencies for the animation
7. Check [SSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Server-side_rendering) (server-side rendering) Issues: This component is a client component, but the page where I import my animation is not marked with use client.  However, marking it as use client also did not bring any change
8. Rebuild: I did in fact rebuild the project from scratch. I created a new Next.js project and migrated page by page adapting tot he Next.js logic.
9. Test in different browsers: It does not work in all major browsers
10. No compatibility issues
11. Consider using a different animation library: I do not use any animation library. This is my custom code, and I do not want to. As this would be a regression.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77162428/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: Re *"regression"*: Do you mean *"[digression](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digression#Noun)"*?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you are using the same code. There isn't any @tailwind directive in your global CSS file.

Comment: I am, I just created this codesandbox to show the whole code and here I forgot to add it. But I have it in my code as Next autoconfigures tailwind.

Answer (score -4):

Here are a few things you can check:

Check for Console Errors:

Open the browser's developer console and see if there are any error messages. This can give you a clue as to what might be going wrong.
Check if IntersectionObserver is Supported:

Ensure that the IntersectionObserver API is supported in the environment you're testing. It might not be supported in some older browsers.
Check if ref.current is Valid:

In your useEffect, add a console.log(ref.current) to make sure that ref.current is not null. If it's null, the observer won't be attached.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) setVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
  });

  if (ref.current !== null) {
    console.log(ref.current); // Check if ref.current is not null
    observer.observe(ref.current);
  }

  return () => {
    observer.disconnect();
  };
}, [ref]);
```

1. Check CSS and Animations:

Verify that your CSS animations are correctly defined in your Tailwind config. The keyframes and animations should be defined correctly.

2. Check Parent Component:

Ensure that the parent component where you're using ScrollAnimation is also being rendered properly and that there are no conflicting styles or animations affecting it.

2. Check Dependencies:

Make sure that all your dependencies in your Next.js project are up-to-date, including React, and any other libraries you might be using.

3. Check SSR (Server-Side Rendering) Issues:

If you're using Next.js with server-side rendering, be aware that IntersectionObserver might not work as expected because it relies on the browser's viewport.

4. Rebuild the Project:

Sometimes, after migrating or making significant changes, it helps to rebuild the project to ensure that all files and dependencies are in sync.

5. Test in Different Browsers:

Try testing your application in different browsers to see if the issue is specific to a certain browser.

6. Verify Versions:

Double-check the versions of React, Next.js, and any other relevant libraries. There might be compatibility issues.

7. Consider Using a Different Animation Library:

If the issue persists, you might want to consider using a different animation library that is known to work well with Next.js.

Comment: I use of course up to date deps and have no errors in the console logs, otherwise I would add it. Thats why it is strange as the setup works with CRA and React + Vite but not with Next. I added answers to your other suggestions as Edit to my question. Maybe the reason here really lies with SSR but I am not sure about that and marking as use client also didnt help

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: This answer is definitely from ChatGPT.